# Mi header es un desastre con position: fixed;

Tags: css, html5, css3

Tengo una página web. Toda funciona bien hasta ahora:

[image: Página web base funcionando correctamente.]

Pero se me ha ocurrido hacer que mi `header` sea fijo en la página, para lo que recurrí a usar `position: fixed;`.
El `header` se vuelve un total desastre desordenado:

[image: Página web con header fijo.]

Lo de la superposición es entendible, porque eso es fácil de arreglar, pero por lo demás, el `header` se vuelve un auténtico licuado, y no he logrado arreglarlo.

Cosas que he intentado:

- Hacer que un div sea fijo y que el header sea contenido por el div para poder poner `position: relative` al header.
- Reconstruir el CSS.

Programación de mi header:

HTML:

```
<header><div id="navbar_left"><a href="subpages/howtouse.html"><img src="code/assets/icons/help.png" class="icon" alt="Help" id="help" /></a><a href="#"><img src="code/assets/logo.png" alt="TextTool" id="logo" onclick='toaster.animate()' /></a></div>
    <div id="navbar_right"><p id="langchange">Offered by TechMan Walker in:</p><select id="language"><option value="en">English&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;▼</option><option value="es">Español&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp▼</option></select></div>
    </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #070707;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #cccccd;
    font-family: "Acherus", "Arial";
    word-break: break-word;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    background-color: #333339;
    padding: 1em;
    width: auto;
    height: 2em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}

/* Barra superior - División izquierda */ #navbar_left {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Barra superior - División derecha */
#navbar_right {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#navbar_left .icon, #navbar_right .icon {
    padding-top: auto;
    padding-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

#logo {
    background-color: #00000000;
    width: 5.6em;
    padding: 0px;
}

#help {
    cursor: help;
}

select {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #000000;
    linear-gradient:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0.7em;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo lograr que me salga como en la primera imagen y que quede fijo en la página sin moverse?

Gracias y espero que me puedas ayudar. ¡Ten un lindo día!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

varias cosas, la forma de hacer que un fixed se vea por encima de todos los demás elementos en pantalla es z-index:1000, le pones un valor y vas probando hasta que tengas el header por encima de los demás elementos con un z-index inferior.

Recuerda que cuando le das a un elemento position:fixed, este pierde el flujo de elementos en la pantalla, ósea que los elemento se colocan delante o detrás de el pero nunca a continuación como en el flujo normal de position:auto

También cambie el width:auto a max-width:100%, eso podría ser una razón por la cual tu elementos no se posiciona correctamente en el top de la pagina.

Otra solución es que le des al header las siguientes propiedades

```
header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  max-width:100%;
  height:70px;   /* Por darle un valor fijo para evitar conflictos con :auto */
  z-index:1000000  /* Exagero el valor de z-index porque no se que z-index tengas puesto en el resto de tu css*/
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Mi capa de elementos flotantes es la número 99, y la altura del header ahora es de 2em. Puse un espacio vacío en la página para evitar que la barra de navegación cubra mis herramientas. Me has dado la salida a mis problemas. ¡Ten un lindo día!